# Change cell name in R using a function

Tags: r, function

Consider the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(rep(1,10),1:10,rep(5,10))
```

I want to replace all the cells with the value 1 in column two with the value 2. I want to create a function that do that. I create the following function:

```
test <- function(x,q,y,z) {
  x$q <- gsub(y, z, x$q)
}
```

But when I apply the code:

```
df$X1.10 <- test(df,X1.10,"1","2")
```

I get an error. Why do I get an error? It is working if I don't include the "z" parameter in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `[[`, pass the column name as string and return the dataset in the function

```
test <- function(x,q,y,z) {
    x[[q]] <- gsub(y, z, x[[q]])
    x
  }

test(df, "X1.10", "1", "2")
```

-output

```
#     rep.1..10. X1.10 rep.5..10.
#1           1     2          5
#2           1     2          5
#3           1     3          5
#4           1     4          5
#5           1     5          5
#6           1     6          5
#7           1     7          5
#8           1     8          5
#9           1     9          5
#10          1    20          5
```

---

If we need to change only a fixed match and no substring, we don't need a `gsub`, it can be just `==` i.e. create a logical expression with `==` and use that to assign

```
test <- function(x,q,y,z) {
   i1 <- x[[q]] == y
    x[[q]][i1] <- z
    x
  }

 test(df, "X1.10", "1", "2")
#   rep.1..10. X1.10 rep.5..10.
#1           1     2          5
#2           1     2          5
#3           1     3          5
#4           1     4          5
#5           1     5          5
#6           1     6          5
#7           1     7          5
#8           1     8          5
#9           1     9          5
#10          1    10          5
```

---

With `regex`, one option is add the start (`^`) and end (`$`) by `paste`ing.  Also, if this occurs only once, then we need to use only `sub` and not `gsub` (global substitution)

```
test <- function(x,q,y,z) {
     y <- paste0("^", y, "$")
    x[[q]] <- sub(y, z, x[[q]])
    x
  }

test(df, "X1.10", "1", "2")
```

---

In case, we want to pass unquoted column names, use `deparse/substitute`

```
test <- function(x,q,y,z) {
    q <- deparse(substitute(q))
    x[[q]] <- gsub(y, z, x[[q]])
    x
  }

test(df, X1.10, "1", "2")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Just one quick question: If I only want to substitute if the value is 1 (and only 1), how do I do that? In this case, I also change 10 to 20 (because it contain 1).

Comment: @Michael I updated with two options. Hope it helps